# I'm trying to implement a C++ program for Kruskal algorithm which requires me to sort the graph by weights.How can I sort my STRUCTURE by WEIGHTS

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

I'm trying to implement a C++ program for Kruskal algorithm which requires me to sort the graph by weights.I'm trying using vectors(structures) but the sorting function seems to give all zeroes.How can I sort my STRUCTURE by WEIGHTS.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct graph
{
    int src;
    int dst;
    int weight;
};

bool compare(struct graph a,struct graph b)
{
    return (&a.weight < &b.weight);
}

int main()
{
    int ver,edges;
    cin >> ver >> edges;

    vector<graph> G(100);
    for(int i=0; i<edges; ++i)
    {
        cin >> G[i].src >> G[i].dst >> G[i].weight;
    }

    sort(G.begin(),G.end(),compare); //trying to sort by weights
    for(int i=0; i<edges; ++i)
    {
        cout << G[i].src << G[i].dst << G[i].weight << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `&` in

```
bool compare(struct graph a,struct graph b)
{
  return (&a.weight < &b.weight);
}
```

takes the address, i.e. you're not comparing the weights, but their addresses. Simply omit the `&`, but also avoid unnecessary copies and take the graph arguments via const reference, i.e.

```
bool compare(graph const & a, graph const & b)
{
  return a.weight < b.weight;
}
```

Finally, you can do this directly via a lambda as in

```
std::sort(G.begin(), G.end(),[](graph const&l, graph const&r)
                             { return l.weight < r.weight; });
```

Comment: it's my pleasure -- actually I'm grateful that you like it, not everybody would have like it that somebody else fiddles with their answer like that.

Comment: @Walter - I'm so bad in english that any help is welcome; but, in this case, your edit greatly improved my answer also.